# Smart contract interaction error "code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bignumber/5.1.1)"

Tags: character-encoding, solidity, smartcontracts, voting, etherscan

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVdIY.jpg)

Hello.

How can i solve this?
Thanks

I think there should be some kind of symbol betveen values, but i tryed different symbols, but dose not work for me. I don't know much about smartcontracts and solidity and what type of symbols should be used.
I apriciate the help.

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577). Instead, format code as a [code block]. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.

Answer (score 0):

BlockScan UI accepts array wrapped in square brackets, with values separated by comma.

Applied to your `choices` example:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```